# Where I can Find java.net.http package Jar file?

Tags: java, http, jar

I have searched too much but still didn't find nothing . I want a jar file which contains these classes.

```
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
```

My compiler doesn't support these imports . So, I want a jar .
Please help me

Comment: What is your SDK and target version?

Comment: I am not using android studio. I am using eclipse

Comment: So, Please give me jar file if you have. Please help me

Comment: "The jar file" can be downloaded from Oracle but should be in your SDK, if the version contains it. If you are below version 11 it is not supported and will probably not even compile if you just add the jar. There may be backports but I am not aware of that, at the moment. So please, just answer the question, so we can help you with your actual problem.

Comment: *"Please help me"* - If you want more help, answer Fildor's question first.

Comment: My Compiler only supports Java 8 . So, Is there any option to get these classes in Java 8.

Comment: No.  There aren't any options with Java 8.  If you want to use those packages you need Java 11 or later.  As the javadoc for those classes says "Added in Java 11".

Comment: Please do not tell like this.. I have already done much progress

Comment: That package was introduced in version 11 as per docs. That's not something _we_ decided ... You can now chose to upgrade your project to a higher version or use what is available in Java 8 to get the job done.

Comment: So, does there any other packages like org.apache.http

Comment: Of course there are.  But why don't you just upgrade to Java 11?

Comment: I am working with appinventor sources. I am making a extension . and Appinventor is based on Java 8 . So, I have to work on Java 8 only

Comment: OK.  Then https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ is probably what you need.  (Or maybe HttpURLConnection ... though that is far less functional.)

Comment: Mind you if AppInventor still doesn't support Java 11, there is a risk that it will become a dead-end platform.

Comment: this one won't work for me

Comment: Is there any other library ??

Comment: @Aryan - If those alternatives won't work, I suggest you start Googling.  (I'm sure there are other alternatives, though there is no guarantee they will "work for you".)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

jdk8 does not contains these classes,you can use
`URConnection connection = URL.openConnection()`

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Comment: Oh really? It most certainly does: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html

Comment: Hey ! your code is working for me. Thanks

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ... yes REALLY. You linked to JDK11. As OP said, JDK 8 does not include this.

Comment: @Lenny You may want to check the edit history of this answer. When I posted my comment the answer just said _"jdk"_, not _"jdk8"_.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thaaaat makes a lot more sense. Thanks for clarifying. Sorry for assuming.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it at this link for the OpenJDK version (here for the JDK 11 version):

https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11

Steps:

- download the full JDK for the version and platform that you need (os, linux or win).
- unzip it, navigate to the jmods folder
- find the `java.net.http.jmod` file. Use it "as is" or rename it to `java.net.http.jar`